# Does Stunned make you Flat-Footed?

Tags: conditions, pathfinder-2e

Stunned does not *explicitly* make you Flat-Footed, but common sense and the first sentence implies it (CR p622):

> You’ve become **senseless**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are independent conditions, despite the poor description for Stunned.

Note that Confused and Unconscious do explicitly include Flat-footed, for example. Stunned is more about denying willful actions.

Comment: I think Paralyzed would be a better Condition to reference as an example that included flat-footed in its penalties

Comment: Ah yeah that's good reasoning